# Etymology: Reduced Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, terminology

If I may request the knowledge of the community on a point of trivia again, I was wondering if anyone could explain to me the etymology of *reduced rings*, that is, rings with no non-zero nilpotent elements.

In what sense is it actually *reduced*? In what sense has a process of *reduction* from an earlier state of things taken place?

Comment: See MF Atiyah & IG Macdonald, Introduction to commutative algebra (1969), page 52 for "primary decomposition [of an *ideal*] is said to be *minimal* (or irredundant, or *reduced*, or normal)." And see Ernst Kunz,  Introduction to commutative algebra and algebraic geometry (1980), page 6 for the [radical $Rad(I)$ of an ideal $I$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_ideal). ... $Rad(0)$ is called 
the *nilradical* of $R$.  A ring $R$ is called *reduced* if $Rad(0) = (0)$... For any ring $R$ ... it is called the *reduced ring* belonging to $R$."

Comment: A quotient ring is usually "simpler" than the original, and if something is preserved between the two (like the prime spectrum) then you'd want to work with the simpler version of the ring, right?  That's when reduction is useful, when the things you want to pay attention to stay the same while your object of study is simpler.

Comment: I'd mark Mauro Allegranza's comment as correct, had it not been for that one cannot do that with a mere comment. Thank you.

Comment: @StormyTeacup Sadly, many good (and a couple of bad) answers on this site waste away as comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a guess:

Given an algebraically closed field $k$, and an ideal $I\subseteq R = k[X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n]$, the correspondences between the quotient ring $R/I$ and the set of points in $k^n$ where all elements of $I$ evaluate to $0$ is heavily studied, and it's one of the main backdrops to the entire mathematical field of algebraic geometry. These correpondences are so strong that from time to time terminology leaks through from one to the other.

I suspect that that has happened here. Nilpotent elements of $R/I$ corresponds to "multiple roots" (in a certain generalized sense) of $I$ in $k^n$. If $R/I$ is reduced, then the zero set of $I$ in $k^n$ is similarily reduced to only single roots.

The actual reduction operation we are talking about here would be to divide out by the nilradical, i.e. the ideal consisting of all the nilpotent elements.